# Commited (no push) to local branch, now i prefer the commits in a different branch

Tags: git

I have locally commited severela times to a certain branch (called master-branch). Now i figure out that would better go to a different branch (feature-branch). I have not pushed the commits. Can i open the feature-branch so that he contains my commits? And that the commits do not go to the master branch?

Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure that you have no uncommitted changes (i.e. the output of `git status` should be empty) - this is so that you can safely use `git reset --hard` at a later stage.  Once you're sure of that then you can do the following:

Make sure that you're on `master-branch`:

```
git checkout master-branch
```

Create a new branch based on your current commit called `feature-branch`:

```
git branch feature-branch
```

Reset your `master-branch` back to an earlier commit:

```
git reset --hard <EARLIER-COMMIT>
```

If you want to go back to the last unpushed change to `master-branch`, then `<EARLIER-COMMIT>` might be `origin/master-branch`.